# Memory/Time Efficient Database Entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a foreach loop that iterates through an array.

In each instance, I organise the array into a query string and use MySQLi to add it to the database.

```
function storeProperties($data, $db) {
    foreach ($data['property'] as $property) {
        $query_string = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(..., ..., ...,)"
        $db->query($query_string);
        echo $db->error;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way I should be doing this?
Obviously, this method uses *n* database queries one after another so this is memory intensive and time intensive.

Is there a better way to do this?
Should I be concatenating each query into a single string and running it all outside the for loop?

Comment: Please note that PHP concat also uses memory and CPU power because you need to calculate if the concat query fits within the max packet size packet off the server (defualt 1Mb) setting on MySQL.

Comment: Yes. Build the whole query string (except "INSERT INTO table VALUES") inside the loop and then execute it once the loop is finished. That way, there's only one round trip to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is from my PDO workhorse, used for bulk insertions. It creates a single INSERT statement with multiple VALUES entries.

Use it as

```
$db->bulkinsert(
    'tbl_my_tablename',
    array('fieldname_1','fieldname_2', 'fieldname_3'),
    array(
       /* rec1 */ array('r1f1', 'r1f2', 'r1f3'),
       /* rec2 */ array('r2f1', 'r2f2', 'r2f3'),
       /* rec3 */ array('r3f1', 'r3f2', 'r3f3')
    ));
```

Please note that the method is an snip from a complex class definition, some methods used here are not contained in the code snippet, especially `$this->connect()` (connects to PDO),`$this->begin()` (starts transaction), `$this->commit()`and `$this->rollback()`, and the static `Log` class for Logging similar to Apache Commons ;-)

But I'm sure this is what you might need.

```
    /**
     * Performs fast bulk insertion
     * Parameters:
     *     $tablename
     *     $datafields - non-assiciative array of fieldnames
     *                   or propertynames if $data is an array of objects
     *     $data       - array of either non-associative arrays (in the correct order)
     *                   or array of objects with property names matching the $datafields array
     */
    const MAX_BULK_DATA = 3000;
    public function bulkinsert($tablename, $datafields, &$data) {
        $result = 0;
        try {
            try {
                $this->connect();
                $datacount = count($data);
                // loop until all data has been processed
                $start = 0;
                $lastbinds = 0;
                $this->begin();
                while ($start < $datacount) {
                    $ins = array();
                    $bindscount = min(self::MAX_BULK_DATA, $datacount - $start);
                    if ($bindscount != $lastbinds) {
                        // prepare the binds
                        $binds = substr(str_repeat(',?', count($datafields)), 1);
                        $binds = substr(str_repeat(",($binds)", $bindscount), 1);
                        $lastbinds = $bindscount;
                    }
                    for ($go = $start, $last = $start + $bindscount; $go < $last; $go++) {
                        if (is_object($data[$go])) {
                            try {
                                foreach($datafields as $propname) {
                                    $rfl = new ReflectionProperty($data[$go], $propname);
                                    $rfl->setAccessible(true);
                                    $ins[] = $rfl->getValue($data[$go]);
                                }
                            }
                            catch(ReflectionException $e) {
                                throw new InvalidArgumentException('PDOCONNECT_ERR_SQL_UNKNOWN_PROPERTY', 0, $e);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            foreach($data[$go] as $value) {
                                $ins[] = $value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES %s', $tablename, join(',',$datafields), $binds);
                    Log::trace($sql);
                    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute($ins);
                    $start = $last;
                    $result += $bindscount;
                }
                $this->commit();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                // do something with the exception if necessary
                throw $e;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->rollback();
            throw $e;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```